# How to update my blog post on GitHub Page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have managed to set up a GitHub page as my personal portfolio.  Now I know how to download and use other pre-defined theme.  The question is how do I add and update my post in my portfolio.

My assumption is I have to generate local MD file and save it in the posts folder and then update certain link in the html file.  Is there a tool that I only need to worry about the content writing, not paying much attention about the updating, formatting stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there a tool that I only need to worry about the content writing, not paying much attention about the updating, formatting stuff"—that's exactly [what Markdown itself is for](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). I'm a bit confused about what you're asking. If you've already managed to set up a GitHub Pages site, what's stopping you from simply updating your source files and pushing your new content up?

Comment: I mean if i choose to set up website from zero, instead of using github page.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your comment and your question don't seem to say the same thing. In any case, asking us to find or recommend a tool is off-topic here.